# How to include the `titlefont` attribute in a plotly template?

Tags: python, plotly

When I create a template with `plotly.io.to_templated()`, the titlefont attribute is excluded from the template.

I create the template following the instructions at https://medium.com/@plotlygraphs/introducing-plotly-py-theming-b644109ac9c7 which results in this minimal example:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio

# Layout
layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(titlefont=dict(size=18), zeroline=False),
        yaxis=dict(titlefont=dict(size=18), zeroline=False),
        width=550,
        height=500,
    )

# Figure
fig = go.Figure(data=None, layout=layout)

# Create template
template = pio.to_templated(fig)
```

The resulting `template.layout` object strips the titlefont from the template part and puts it in the rest of the layout:

```
Layout({
    'template': {'layout': {'height': 500, 'width': 550, 'xaxis': {'zeroline': False}, 'yaxis': {'zeroline': False}}},
    'xaxis': {'title': {'font': {'size': 18}}},
    'yaxis': {'title': {'font': {'size': 18}}}
})
```

When I then apply this template to another figure, only the `template` part of the above object is applied and the `titlefont` attribute is ignored.

Is there a way to save the `titlefont` property to the template?